# Policies work locally, but do not work once deployed to Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-appservice

I am using ASP.NET Core 6.0 and deploying to Azure App Service. And I am having a weird issue where Azure AD based Policies work when I spin up locally in development mode, but they do not when pushed to Azure App Service; authorized pages throw 403s.

```csharp
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    // options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    options.AddPolicy("Writers", policy => policy.RequireRole("Task.Write"));
    options.AddPolicy("Approvers", policy => policy.RequireRole("Task.Approve"));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

I am now suspecting this part of code has something to do with it. But not too sure.

```csharp
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts(); // This line?
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: If you suspected that line had something to do with the issue, you could always remove them, deploy, and see if that makes a difference. I doubt those lines are your issue however. Do you use the same settings your appsetting.json in both environments? Do you perhaps have extra settings in appsettings.Development.json that you're not deploying to Azure?

Comment: @mason no separate app settings. You are right. I will remove that line them deploy to see if that makes any difference. I feel like I forgot something on app service configuration end.

Comment: If you add the [redirect url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#add-a-redirect-uri) of the azure web app? I mean you may add redirect url like `https://localhost:44231/home` for your developing, and now you've published it to azure, then you may should add another redirect url like `xx.azurewebsite.xxx/home`